# Strings Comparing between result set and correct set

Tags: string-matching

I'm working on an algorithm to extract keywords from a text, I have a test set of scientific abstracts with their tags (keywords) , my question is What is the best way to compare the correct tags with the tags my algorithm produce ?

Should I strictly compare them ex. 
    if (correct_tag == result_tag)

...or do a similarity check ? Given that sometimes I get something like the following:

For the same document:

```
**correct_tag** =  ["eigenvalues and eigenfunctions in quantum mechanics"]
**result_tag** = ["eigenvalues and eigenfunctions"]
```

For Another Document:

```
**correct_tag** = ["cardiovascular system"]
**result_tag** = ["cardiovascular physiology",""cardiovascular system""]
```

NOTE: These tags are in text tags , meaning they are extracted from the text

Guys any help is appreciated , thanks